# CodeIgniter validation rule

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my rule in form_validation.php in config that calls a function in MY_Form_validation.php which extends CI_Form_validation.

form_validation.php rule:

```
array(
        'field' => 'phone',
        'label' => 'Phone',
        'rules' => 'is_valid_phone'
    ),
```

MY_Form_validation.php method:

```
public function is_valid_phone($phone)
    {
        echo 'phone validation: '.$phone;
        return preg_match("/\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]\d{4}/x", $phone) ? true : false;
    }
```

The others rules in form_validation that don't call is_valid_phone and is_valid_postal_code work fine on dev and production. For some reason these 2 methods work on dev but not on production. The php version are slightly different. 5.2.8 on dev and 5.2.17 on prod. All the files are synched, I can confirm that. I've put an echo statement in the is_valid_phone method and it displays on dev but not on prod.

I don't know what the problem could be. Any idea?

Thanks guys.

Comment: have you tried it with `$this->set_message("is_valid_phone", "The %s is in an invalid phone format XXX-XXX-XXXX");`

Comment: have you setup the lang file for the message of a valid phone?

Comment: $CI->form_validation->set_message('is_valid_phone','error');
        $CI->form_validation->set_message('is_valid_postal_code','error');

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the echo . You have some kind of cache or something goes wrong with the echo before some headers are shown.

Try to do put the echo value on a string and will work for sure. Also you can simply try to use the load->view method. Just try this:

```
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci->load->view('just_echo',array('data' => 'phone validation: '.$phone));
```

and the view just_echo.php will be:

```
    <?php
            echo $data;
    ?>
```

Comment: I had it without an echo before and it didn't work. The echo shows on my dev server and the validation rule works.

Comment: perhaps if you use the set_message will work. It's for sure something with the echo.

Comment: Found the solution, the filename was My_Form_validation. Renamed it to MY... and it works!